# Can I put nylon strings on Martin D28 Dreadnought?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I would like to play some Spanish classical music on my Martin D28. And I was wondering would it be possible to put nylon strings on it and which kind you would recommend?

Thanks

Comment: They don't make nylon strings with ball ends for that type guitar.  But you might want to try Silk and Steel Acoustic Strings which are softer to the touch and feel more like nylon strings that regular steel strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.  I am coming from experience with classical guitars.  Strings for steel string guitars have a large metal ball bearing of sorts on one end that goes into a hole in the tail piece (behind the bridge).  Nylon strings usually do not have this and need to be tied at both ends (not a real knot but a twist that is held in place under tension).  Also most nylon strings are quite fat compared to their steel string counterparts and will not fit into the grooves in the nut or bridge that keep the string in place.  Lastly, even if you were to find a set of strings that fit nylon string guitars usually have a soft wood top whereas steel string acoustics might have a hard wood top.  And both have different bracing inside.  This amounts to a completely different tone and I am not sure that nylon strings would sound very good on a steel string acoustic.

If you really want to start playing classical or flamenco I'd suggest investing in a low cost but decent quality beginner classical guitar.

Comment: You'd probably have to drop all the tension off the truss rod too, or the neck will pull back like crazy.

Comment: Good point, but I doubt you could get that far.